# (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'(PHYTON OPEN CV ERROR)

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np


faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("Resouces/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True :
    #kare kare webcam den gelen görüntü yakalanıyor
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30,30),
        #cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
         )

    #TANIMLANAN YÜZÜN ETRAFINDA YEŞİL BİR KARE OLUŞTURULUYOR
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y)+(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    #SONUC EKRANDA GÖSTERİLİYOR.
    cv2.imshow('Video',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    #HERŞEY TAMAMSA EKRAN YAKALAMASI SERBEST BIRAKILIYOR.
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> File "C:/Users/EMRE/PycharmProjects/OpencvPhyton/chapter4.py", line
> 14, in 
> gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1)
> C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-oduouqig\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
> 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: check if the `read()` operator is successful with `if ret==False: break` before `gray = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In two last codes, delete the space. Then, please add the data source for faceCascade. I discards some of your parameters in faces expression because I realized that you chose some wrong ones. Please fix it by yourself.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True :
    #kare kare webcam den gelen görüntü yakalanıyor
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray)

    #TANIMLANAN YÜZÜN ETRAFINDA YEŞİL BİR KARE OLUŞTURULUYOR
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

    #SONUC EKRANDA GÖSTERİLİYOR.
    cv2.imshow('Video',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    #HERŞEY TAMAMSA EKRAN YAKALAMASI SERBEST BIRAKILIYOR.
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: but I ran into a problem the camera turned on but it gets my face too close how can i fix it?